# How to reuse a stringstream in C++?

Tags: c++, stringstream

So I'm experimenting with stringstream in C++ and I'm wondering why input3 were to stay the same. If I inputted: "test", "testing", and "tester", input1, input2, and input3 would all respectively have their corresponding string variable. But when I re-enter in values let say only "test" and "testing", the "tester" variable would still be in the stream from the previous input. How do I clear it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    std::string input, input1, input2, input3;
    std::string x, y, z;
    std::string other;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::istringstream getter{input};
    getter >> input1 >> input2 >> input3;
    while (input1 != "break"){
        if (input1 == "test"){
            function(input2, input3);
            std::getline(std::cin, other); //receive more input
            getter.str(other);
            getter >> x >> y >> z; //get new data
            input1 = x; input2 = y; input3 = z; //check against while loop
        }

        else{
            std::cout << "WRONG!" << std::endl;
            std::getline(std::cin, input);
            getter >> input1 >> input2 >> input3;

        } 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `getter.str(std::string())` should do the trick. (provided that's the stream you're trying to clear) Let me know if that doesn't work for ya.

Comment: How about a simple [assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/operator%3D) like `getter = std::istringstream{otherinput}`?

Comment: @Phixle I tried that and it didn't work. Is it possible to clear a stream, receive input, and insert it into the same stream with the same variables?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you're not checking for success or failure. `getter >> x >> y >> z;` fails, so you go on to work with whatever values `x,y,z` still held from the previous read.

Comment: @M.M Would it be possible to use the same string stream in a while loop? After receiving data, clearing the stringstream and using the same variables to insert into the stringstream?

Comment: @programmer2222 you mean use the same variables to extract from the stream, and yes. Look at R Sahu's answer, or in the "Related" bar to the right

Answer (score 2):

The program below shows how to change the `string` associated with a `stringstream` and extract data from the new `string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   std::string input1 = "1 2";
   std::string input2 = "10 20";

   std::istringstream iss{input1};
   int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;

   // Read everything from the stream.
   iss >> v1 >> v2;
   std::cout << "v1: " << v1;
   std::cout << ", v2: " << v2 << std::endl;

   // Reset the string associated with stream.
   iss.str(input2);

   // Expected to fail. The position of the stream is
   // not automatically reset to the begining of the string.
   if ( iss >> v1 >> v2 )
   {
      std::cout << "Should not come here.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Failed, as expected.\n";

      // Clear the stream
      iss.clear();

      // Reset its position.
      iss.seekg(0);

      // Try reading again.
      // It whould succeed.
      if ( iss >> v1 >> v2 )
      {
         std::cout << "v1: " << v1;
         std::cout << ", v2: " << v2 << std::endl;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output, with g++ 4.8.4 on Linux:

```
v1: 1, v2: 2
Failed, as expected.
v1: 10, v2: 20
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep receiving input in a while loop, (the input being the same variable name), clear the stream, and keep inserting fresh new input?

Comment: I don't think seekg is necessary - `.str()` implies reasserting the stream's open-mode